# Repeatedly run function on mouseover

Tags: jquery, setinterval, mouseover

Trying to get a function to run continuously when the mouse is over a div.
How can I get the repeat() function to only run when the mouse is over the div?

```
function repeat(){
  window.setInterval(console.log("Mouse is on image"), 1000)};
$("div.mainGif").mouseover(repeat());
```

I also tried it this way using an anonymous function,

```
$("div.mainGif").mouseover(function(){window.setInterval(console.log("Mouse is on image"), 1000)});
```

But that doesn't work at all.

Comment: It would have to be `$("div.mainGif").mouseover(repeat);` since you are supposed to pass a `function` to `mouseover()` (not whatever that function returns).

Comment: Ok I made that change but still not working. Thanks

Comment: You need to pass a function to `setInterval`. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this and give us a note how it goes:

```
var interval;
function repeat(){
  interval = window.setInterval(function() { console.log("Mouse is on image") }, 1000)
};
$("div.mainGif").on({
  mouseover: repeat,
  mouseout: function() { window.clearInterval(interval); }
});
```

Comment: Excellent that works and clearing the set interval too. I was also making a mistake using div. as this class is on an img tag so I needed either img.mainGif or just .mainGif. Thanks again!